# F#: why to have both '::' and '@'

Tags: f#

I started to read about F# recently, and obviously I got one novice-level question very soon. It is about lists (collections).

According to F# manuals, there are two operations to construct lists, they are cons (aka `::`) and `@`. Given the fact `@` is more versatile (can merge sublists, not single elements, and can append to the tail as well, unlike the cons operation), my question is: at which situation we **must** use exactly `::` instead of `@` to avoid ambiguity, or non-wanted side-effects and so on?

In other words: is `::` theoretically redundant or not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `list` type has two constructors: `[]` and `::`. If `::` were removed, only the `[]` constructor would be left, making it impossible to create non-empty lists.

Note that something like `[1;2;3]` is syntactic sugar for `1::2::3::[]`, so it relies on the existence of `::`.

Similarly, `@` is a function that's defined using `::`, so if `::` didn't exist, neither could `@`.

Note that `@` isn't suitable as a replacement for `::` in `list`'s definition as, if you don't already have a way to construct non-empty lists, `@` can't be used to create them (`[] @ []` is still an empty list).

And even if you added a constructor for single-item lists, `@` would lead to an ambiguous representation because `[1;2;3]` could be represented either as `([1] @ [2]) @ [3]` or as `[1]  @ ([2] @ [3])` (plus, you could just add `@ []` anywhere you want). So you'd end up with several different representations for semantically equivalent lists.

Comment: I think one important point to note is that `@` is slower than `::` for equivalent results.

Comment: I'm confused by your last paragraph. You're basically saying that `@` is associative while `::` is right-associative. But why is this a problem? +1 for the rest of the answer though!

Comment: @sebhofer Constructors aren't associative. If @ were a constructor, `([1] @ [2]) @ [3]` and `[1] @ ([2] @ [3])` would be different values (you could distinguish them by pattern matching even if you define other operations to treat them the same), even though they logically describe the same list. And that would be problematic.

Answer (score 5):

It's the other way around, `@` is for all intents and purposes redundant, and I believe the reasons for it to exist *as an operator* in the core library are purely historical.

I would argue that it would have been better if it was retired and the usage of `List.append` recommended in its place.

The way things stand today is that `@` is defined in [prim-types.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/76d5288b0b54e20b14a1bf5ca8eb0e9193c5485c/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3639) as an equivalent of the following function:

```
let rec (@) x y = 
    match x with 
    | [] -> y 
    | (h::t) -> h :: (t @ y)
```

and is later [reexposed](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/76d5288b0b54e20b14a1bf5ca8eb0e9193c5485c/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L133) as `List.append`:

```
let append list1 list2 = list1 @ list2
```

There's very little reason why it should be exposed as an operator in the first place, other than "OCaml is doing it".

In practice, it's fairly rare to have a valid case for appending lists and much of collection processing in F# happens using sequences or other collection types that are better suited to concatenation, yet do not offer a dedicated operator for it. Singly-linked lists are very much the textbook example of a structure you do not want to append to.

In that way, `@` is purely educational - it seems like it only exists to trip up newcomers to the language (or remind them to be mindful of performance characteristics of data structures they happen to be using).

Comment: As far as I can see, cons operator is not able to append to the tail, just to the head. Reverting the list, then adding new head, then reverting back could be low-performing, no?

Comment: @YurySchkatula: By definition, you can't really add elements to a singly-linked list from the "tail end". What `@` does, is that it copies the entire left list and points to the right list as the tail of the last copied node.

Comment: A standard recursion pattern is to build up the list in reverse, i.e. you "cons" the elements to the list and reverse it in the base case. That's if you're adding to the list element by element. If you just have two lists that you need to join, go ahead and append (and pay the performance cost), but my point is - you don't need an operator for that when `List.append` makes for readable enough code.

Answer (score 0):

They are two different functions with two behavior which can be used to create a list.

:: operator add an element to a list
@ merge two lists

adding an element one by one is easy with a list. Merging two list require more work.

It is better to use :: operator, and reserve @ operator for merging only purpose.